# Apache poi xlsx generation gets slow with many immages

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm using apache poi 3.14 to generate an xlsx. Everything works correctly but there is a performance degradation after every image added to the workbook.
The method slowing down is createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex) of Drawing class.
is there a better way to add image to an xlsx?

```
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, width * 
Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL, height * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL, columnIndex, rowNum,columnIndex, rowNum);
anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);
byte[] byteStream = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(imagePath));
int pictureIndex = sheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(byteStream, imageType);
drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
```

Comment: Did you try only calling `createDrawingPatriarch` once at the start, and re-using it throughout?

Comment: yes, i've tried to call createDrawingPatriarch only one time and then using getDrawingPatriarch but the problem is still there, everytime i call drawing.createPicture() it gets slower.

Comment: Call create once, store the reference to that somewhere, and re-use that. Processing all the drawing XML into friendly classes is slow!

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm experiencing the exactly same situation.

Comment: Hi, i found that the problem was apache poi version not really streaming the images. The problem has been fixed from version 3.17+

Answer (score 0):

I have dug into this and found the only workaround for this.

I wrote a post about this.
My answer is on https://lhb0517.tistory.com/entry/Apache-poi-many-images-getting-too-slow-exponentially

Please be thoughtful despite the post written in Korean.

However this way isn't suitable for production server, but for troubleshooting.

If you want to work with production server, you might need to manage edited jar separately in private repository(eg. sonarqube, etc)